# Why we need to add argument to plugin?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, plugin, factory

Recently I get through this below set of code and am not sure why the arguments are passed for the plugin.

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterfaceFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="instanceName" xsi:type="string">Mageplaza\EmailAttachments\Mail\Transport</argument>
        </arguments>
        <plugin name="mageplaza_emailattachments_transport_factory" type="Mageplaza\EmailAttachments\Mail\TransportFactory"/>
    </type>
```

Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `argument` pass,
The respective class perform the action.

In other side you can consider that, plugin will perform the task based on the given argument.

Answer (score 0):

It just looks like two things are being defined on the same type.

#### Constructor Argument Replacement

There is a constructor argument replacement defined to change one of the arguments

```xml
<type name="Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterfaceFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="instanceName" xsi:type="string">Mageplaza\EmailAttachments\Mail\Transport</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

#### Interceptor/Plugin Definition

There is a plugin defined, pointing to the class specified.

```xml
<type name="Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterfaceFactory">
    <plugin name="mageplaza_emailattachments_transport_factory" type="Mageplaza\EmailAttachments\Mail\TransportFactory"/>
</type>
```

#### Separate DI/Plugin Declarations

Both are just being defined at the same time. They could have also been declared on two separate `<type />` nodes with the same effect, **although the plugin pointing to a factory seems strange**. If the `Mageplaza\EmailAttachments\Mail\TransportFactory` class is not an actual file that contains before/after/around plugins, it doesn't look necessary or correct. I don't have the `Magaplaza_EmailAttachments` extension to look at, otherwise it might be more clear why that plugin is defined there.

It looks like the intention of the extension and the first argument replacement is to swap out the Mail Transport to allow adding email attachments to an email.

```xml
<type name="Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterfaceFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="instanceName" xsi:type="string">Mageplaza\EmailAttachments\Mail\Transport</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<type name="Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterfaceFactory">
    <plugin name="mageplaza_emailattachments_transport_factory" type="Mageplaza\EmailAttachments\Mail\TransportFactory"/>
</type>
```